# problem with reverted when testing smart contract

Tags: testing, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, hardhat

In my smart contract there is a function:

```
function fund() public payable {
    require(
        msg.value.getConversionRate(priceFeed) >= MINIMUM_USD,
        "You need to spend more ETH!"
    );
    addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
    funders.push(msg.sender);
}
```

when I test **fund()** with is code:

```
beforeEach(async function () {
    deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
    await deployments.fixture(["all"])
    fundMe = await ethers.getContractAt("FundMe", deployer)
    mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContractAt(
        "MockV3Aggregator",
        deployer
    )
})

describe("fund", async function () {
    it("Fails if you don't send enough ETH", async () => {
        await expect(fundMe.fund()).to.be.revertedWith(
            "You need to spend more ETH!"
        )
    })
})
```

I run `yarn hardhat test` then I get :

> ```
>      Fails if you don't send enough ETH:
>  AssertionError: Expected transaction to be reverted with reason 'You need to spend more ETH!', but it didn't revert
>   at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
>   at Context.<anonymous> (test/unit/FundMe.test.js:27:13)
> ```

this is my [code](https://github.com/Vinhnv0901/fund-me) in github

I hope to receive everyone's help and opinions